# How to make Pebble watch vibrate

Tags: pebble-watch

I have a requirement in my program to make the Pebble watch vibrate on an event say when I send a particular string from Android App to my watchapp which is running on Pebble. Is there any function or command I can invoke in my program to make Pebble vibrate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. The Pebble SDK provides a [Vibes module](http://developer.getpebble.com/2/api-reference/group___vibes.html). You'll need to send an [`AppMessage`](http://developer.getpebble.com/2/api-reference/group___app_message.html) from your Android app to your "watchapp". You cannot make the watch vibrate without both interfaces. (You cannot simply pair the devices and issue a command "vibrate!" from your Android app.)

Take a look at ["Integrating Pebble Watchapps with Phone Apps"](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/guides/app-phone-communication.html). You can also get an idea of how transmitting data works in [their sample Android app](https://github.com/pebble/pebblekit/blob/master/Android/PebbleKitExample/src/com/example/PebbleKitExample/ExampleWeatherActivity.java).

Comment: @AravindKamble No problem. If you believe this is the answer to your question, please mark it as the accepted answer so future visitors can find it.